# Fewest bytes to identify a file

Tags: algorithm, search, hash, heuristics

I'm currently working on a little side project, which turns out be a bit of a challenge. This is the setup: I've a fairly old processor which is used in a variaty of out products. There are about 500 different firmware version for various applications. They sometimes differ in a few bytes ~1k, other times only share 5%. Now I'd like to identify each version by creating a unique identifyer for it. I've got the firmewares binary available as files to work and train with.

The goal is, when any device comes by, I want to read out as few bytes as possible of the installed firmware, since the connection is fairly slow with 9600 Baud. Even though the firmware is only about 64k in total, it takes quite some time to read it completely (~5min due to protocol overhead, clock speed etc.)

I was thinking about some logic, that would parse the stored firmware files and determins which of its bytes can be used to uniquely identify it. Whenever a device comes by, it reads each of this fingerprint bytes one atfer the other, pretty much like old T9 text prediction to narrow down the candidates untils it finds the correct firmware. To do that I'd need to build up a db that contains the most optimized set of fingerprint bytes. But how to train it? How to I find the most significant bytes over 500 files?

So far I've tried to statistically analyse the files and find top 50 byte that differ the most between the files. The problem is, that even taking 50 bytes I get multiple versions which create the same hash.

Any suggestions or algorithms that might takle the problem would be very welcome!
If you got an idea for a totally different approch to this, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: Why not use HASH ? ... create a MD5 hash (or any checksum ...) for the entire firmware and send just that ... its highly unlikely you will find 2 different firmwares with the same hash ... and the HASH itself is just few BYTES long ... computing it should be also pretty faster than your 5 min ... but you would need to compute the hash on the device itself ...

Comment: @Spektre It's kind of difficult to compute the hash on the device if the firmware doesn't support doing such a thing.

Comment: well if that is not a possibility then may be some more info about the device would help ... does it have some version info encoded in the code? whats the difference between firmwares (different messages, ) does its internal protocol change ? sending receiving packets, does it have the same commands ? ... all those could be used for detection without actually reading the firmware

Comment: The normal way to do this is that you have a hash of the contents, as has already been mentioned. It can be a hash that you compute, and/or that is part of the data stored to the firmware. For most firmware having a pre-computed hash value stored with the firmware, or at least available when the firmware is being updated is normal. The hash is commonly used to verify that any update was successful (i.e. what was stored was actually the firmware intended).

Comment: Thanks for all the input! To the topics of other markes I can use: For the most part the versions differ in the internal behavior regarding timing and how the peripherials are controlled. So nothing really that I can use for my advantage here. Furthermore the system if very limited regarding the bootloader. It doesn't really offer any ability to check / hash the firmware

Answer (score 5):

Identify all byte positions where values can differ. Then find the "most effective splitter", i.e. the position where probing the value will split the current set in the smallest subsets (in the minmax sense), or the more numerous subsets.

Then repeat the whole procedure with every subset, recursively. This will yield a decision tree giving you (hopefully short) sequences of bytes to test.

This is a heuristic approach, possibly non-optimal and I hope

- that the computation procedure is not too long (though it will be run once for all),
- that it is no too far from the optimum.

Assuming that every split is balanced but results each time in two subsets, the test sequences will not exceed 10 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is what I've done with the 50 bytes as mentioned in my post. I didn't went to the trouble of putting it into a binary tree, but since I've created a hash for each "path" it comes down to the same thing. Even taking 50 bytes where the values differ, didn't suffice to find the correct firmware.
It would need some kind of optimization to reduce the nodes in the tree based on the previously selected path.

Comment: @Corelgott: no, this is not what you have done. The procedure I described guarantees that every single version will be discriminated. If you are lucky, 10 to 20 bytes should suffice. But they are not always at the same locations. Please don't read superficially.

Comment: I concur that this is the most practical approach. It's basically the same as the ID3 algorithm for building a classification tree. Using "hashing" is not a good approach: the system would end up processing more (possibly far more) data than it had to, because it wouldn't be able to adapt its tests to the information it had collected so far.

Comment: I see where you go... The more I think about it, the more promissing the approch apears to be. I've just used the hashes to ensure the path uniqueness. But you are right that hashing them will not use the minimal dataset needed. Non the less the biggest difference to my approch is due to the subdivision, the child groups are optimized in them selfs. Mine lacks this and thus I see the problems I have. I'll give this a go...